# I'm performing a multi linear regression on the The Oxford Covid-19 Government Response Tracker. I have a couple of doubts about the process

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression, correlation

I hope this is the right place to ask this.

I'm currently working my way through a dataset and performing Multiple Linear Regression on it. The data is for Oxford Governement Response Tracker for the US. I have a couple of questions to ask though, various points i'm confused on and would appreciate clarification on:

1. I have about 12 categorical input variables ( ordinal ), i would use chi2 technique to check correlation between each one and the dependent variable (confirmed cases) right ?
2. is df.corr adjusted for Kendall method useful at all in this case?
3. should I scale the input ordinal categorical ordinal variables?
4. Also, finally, a potentially stupid question but It just popped in my head; why don't we just run the multi linear regression and get rid of the variables with p value > 0.05?

Comment: Oh! thank you for pointing me in the right direction! googling problems with stats typically leads me here!

Answer (score 2):

1. Examining correlation between a categorical variable and the outcome is not a great way to determine which variables are "important" since we are not accounting for the effects of other variables.  Here is a simple example.  I will simulate 1000 observations from the following linear model

$$ y = 0.5x - 0.5z + \varepsilon $$

The trick here is that $z$ is correlated with $x$.  We will see that failing to account for $x$ when examining the relationship between $z$ and $y$ will competely obfuscate the effect of $z$.

```r
set.seed(0)
x  = rnorm(1000)
p = ifelse(x<0, 0.25, 0.75)
z = rbinom(1000, 1, p)
y = 0.5*x - 0.5*z + rnorm(1000)

model = lm(y~x+z) 
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x + z)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -3.09980 -0.69652 -0.01183  0.73167  3.01098 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  0.02762    0.04682   0.590    0.555    
#> x            0.51140    0.03569  14.331  < 2e-16 ***
#> z           -0.49972    0.07135  -7.004 4.57e-12 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.033 on 997 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.1722, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1705 
#> F-statistic: 103.7 on 2 and 997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

cor(z, y)
#> [1] -0.04099364
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The correlation between $z$ and $y$ (not accounting for $x$) makes it seem like $z$ has no relationship to $y$.  The linear model correctly estimates the true effect.

2. See 1, don't use correlation to examine two variables in the absence of others.
3. This isn't needed.  You'll should use dummy variables anyway instead of coding them as integers.
4. This approach is not valid for inference.  If you run a regression, and select only the significant variables to rerun the regression with, then the resulting p values of the second regression do not account for the selection procedure and are hence too optimistic.

Comment: 1. I'm trying to adjust for OLS assumptions, hence the check for multi collinearity.

3. Based on what i've understood, you'd use dummy variables where the categories simply imply different items and their order doesn't matter. I've got categorical variables where order in each variable does matter. Think increasing order of alerts : 0 - 4.
4. I understand the need of selecting only the relevant variables for a final regression. Thank you!

Comment: A few things: Multicollinearity will inflate the standard error, but its not a death sentence (unless the variables are measuring the same thing).  The best approach is just to think about the data generating process and what is important to adjust for, rather than "letting the data speak for itself". Additionally, coding an ordinal variable as an integer makes the assumption the effect of going from 0 to 2 is exactly twice that of going form 0 to 1, which may or may not be the case.  Obviously, you have to justify all these choices.

Answer (score 1):

1. What's the outcome variable? You could, but why?
2. Not sure what this is. Presumably it's in the software you're using?
3. You could. No need though.
4. This is called stepwise regression. There's a large literature on why this is a bad idea. But (briefly), you look at the p-values, then you change the analysis based on that, the p-values are no longer correct.

Comment: Not only are the p-values incorrect, all resulting estimates of uncertainty are too optimistic (e.g. confidence intervals are far too narrow because they don't account for the selection procedure uncertainty).

Comment: 1. Outcome variable is confirmed covid cases. A continuous vairable.
2. pandas in built correlation function. adding in the method attribute to use 'Kendall' method for ordinal variables.
3. Thank you!
4. Ok so i had a somewhat correct idea it seems. I appreciate it!