# If I run correlation analysis between two variables and get a non-significant result, is there any point to run regression and include covariates?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance

I ran correlation analysis between two variables and found a very non-significant result. I know that in a case in which you find a significant result, you might want to think about putting the two variables into a multiple regression (with one of the variables as a predictor and the other as response variable) and also including covariates as predictors which you think might contribute to the relationship in order to make sure to account for any confound. But what about my case in which I found no significant correlation between the two variables... could including the variables in regression along with some covariates possibly reveal a significant relationship between my two variables? I think the answer is no, but I want to make sure.

Thanks,
FBH

Comment: Generally data analysis should be guided by a research question of interest. We only "might want to think about putting the two variables into a multiple regression" if we know what we want to find out from this multiple regression. You haven't said anything about what you want to find out. Correlation is symmetric between variables, regression is not. Whether one or the other is more appropriate (or both, or none) depends on the meaning of the variables and how you may want to use one to find out about the other.

Comment: See the first diagram in the Wikipedia article on Simpson's paradox. The better question might be - given the existence of omitted variable bias - why you'd look at the bivariate correlations.

Comment: Thanks Christian and Glen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is "Yes" [as I show here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/543892/im-performing-a-multi-linear-regression-on-the-the-oxford-covid-19-government-r/543895#543895).  The correlation between two variables can be "confounded", a relationship can be obfuscated/be spurious in the absence of other variables (either in your data or not in your data).

Key words to search for on this site are "Confounding", "Omited Variable Bias", and "Stepwise Regression"

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Comment: Hi again Demetri, I have a follow up question. So I realize based on your answer that despite finding a non-significant correlation, a significant relationship might be found when doing regression and including covariates. My question is, about how frequently is this the case? Is it the case that most of the time this isn't the case and if we find a non-significant correlation that it's a relatively safe bet that there is in fact no relationship (were we not to run regression)? Or is it not a relatively safe bet?

Comment: @FastBallooningHead: See my comment above. This totally depends on the meaning of the data, context, what your aim is etc. Surely one can't say anything general of the kind "this almost always or almost never happens". Chances are nobody has done systematic statistics on this because devoid of context it doesn't make much sense to speculate about it.

Comment: @FastBallooningHead Also generally insignificance does *not* mean that there is no relationship. It only means that any relationship that may be there could not be found from your data. The reason for this may just be that you don't have enough data, or that the relationship is existing but weak.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks Christian.